# Filtering postgreSQL jsonb columns with Bookshelf.js & bookshelf-jsonapi-params

Tags: javascript, postgresql, bookshelf.js, json-api

I have a postgreSQL database set up with a Node.js backend using Bookshelf.js as my ORM. My model is:

```
const Maintenance = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'maintenances',
}, {
    jsonColumns: ['attributes']
});
```

I'm using the `bookshelf-jsonapi-params` plugin to return my results using the `fetchJsonApi` method as follows:

```
bookshelf
        .Maintenance
        .fetchJsonApi(req.jsonAPI, true)
        .then(...)
```

In my `maintenances` table I have an `attributes` column of type `jsonb`, which can contain various information:

```
{
    "type": "maintenances",
    "id": "129",
    ...
    "attributes": {
        "date": "2017-11-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        ...
        "type": "normal",
        "attributes": {
            "status": {
                "id": "in-progress",
                "label": "In progress"
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to search/filter on data contained in that column. I have tried many queries such as:

```
/maintenances?filter[like][attributes]=in-progress
--- which results in --->
error: select "maintenances".* from "maintenances" where (LOWER("maintenances"."attributes") like LOWER($1)) - function lower(jsonb) does not exist
```

Or even:

```
/maintenances?filter[attributes]={"status":{"id":"in-progress"\\,"label":"In Progress"}"
--- which results in --->
select "maintenances".* from "maintenances" where "maintenances"."attributes" in ($1) - invalid input syntax for type json
```

From browsing the documentation/issues on bookshelf.js, bookshelf-jsonapi-params and postgreSQL, my understanding is that it doesn't work because postgreSQL simply doesn't handle the `=` comparison between jsonb or the other non-json operators. My question is then: is there even a way of filtering on jsonb columns with that setup ?